# Apache Problem, phpinfo gives following arror

Tags: apache, php

Simply calling phpinfo(); gives the following info..

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/phpinfo.php on line 2

It is a fresh Ubuntu + Apache install on Amazon EC2.

Comment: First rule of getting help on code, is showing the code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible, there has to be something else in the file.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using

```
$this->phpinfo();
```

Try using simply

```
phpinfo();
```

More info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php